# How do I output html markup stored in a xsl:variable

Tags: xslt, xslt-grouping

I am trying to render markup stored in a variable but I am getting no joy. Reason its cached is because I am using this several times in the page

```
<xsl:variable name="imgHtml">
    <figure>
        <img src="{$img}" alt="" class="" />
        <figcaption>
            <p><xsl:value-of select="name" /></p>
            <a href="#">Enlarge Image</a>
        </figcaption>
    </figure>
</xsl:variable>
```

I then reference the variable using the value-of elment 
            `<xsl:value-of select="$imgHtml" />` but for some reason, the HTML does not render. Don't be shy, I need the help. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `<xsl:copy-of select="$imgHtml"/>`, `value-of` always creates a plain text node.

Comment: could you please tell me, how could we resolve the same problem if the variable value itself as HTML content

Answer (score 2):

The other answers were not working for me, however this did:

```
<xsl:value-of select="$variable" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
```